# PHP Token generation encoding/decoding

Tags: php, session, cookies

Part of a favor for a friend i am reviewing his site which is php. I would like to test his session tokens generation functions but i don't have access to the source code. For this reason i am obtaining a number of tokens, attempting to find correlation between them and analyze them using Burp. The one thing that i haven't conclude yet is if the tokens are encrypted or not and of course if they are encrypted i am looking at a completely different approach. The tokens i get for each request i make are the following:

- __utma numeric value
- __utm  numeric value
- __utmc numeric value
- __utmz numeric value

and a final one named 32b7e298af200c063ff686fa5dc74c3f with the value 44822a2f5e3db0931da0c444fa50a96a

I dont care about the first 3 tokens since they are default tokens since they are used for Google analytics purposes. For the last token is it possible to decode it and can you identify the encoding scheme used?

I dont mind posting the actual tokens here since i am not registered as a user in the first place and the site is still at development stage for error detection.

thank you in advance

Comment: Reviewing his site but don't have access to the code, call me cynical but something doesn't add up here, especially getting someone to review his site that doesn't know anything about sessions and how they are managed.

Comment: Well putting up a php site isnt rocket science. If you are implying i am trying to do something without the proper authorization dont you think that i would try for something bigger? I guess i am the person not knowing anything about sessions? please elaborate on that.

Comment: You are asking how to encode and decode a php session id. They are not encoded or decoded, there is no data in the session id to decode.

Comment: @Anigel - let me get this straight and make sure my understanding is correct or wrong. Isnt it possible in the session ID to contain data such as my username or a combination of other data? i would assume based on my understanding that it could contain lets say my username + myip + my status (lets say logged in). i understand that session ids can be comprised of any data which are then for example base-64 decoded by the server. help me clarify please

Comment: No the session id contains nothing, it just points to a session file on the server which contains that data. the session id is just that it is an id. But you were already told this in the answer from ThiefMaster

Comment: @Anigel - Quoting from the "The web application Hackers Handbook" which as i understand is a well respected book... Some session tokens are created using a transformation of the users username or email address or other information associated with that person. This information may be encoded or obfuscated in some way and may be combined with other data......Attackers can exploit the meaning within this session token to attempt to guess the current sessions of other application systems. This contradicts what you mention above. Am i missing something?

Comment: I think i answered my own question. I mixed up sessions and tokens. my original question was regarding tokens. as you can see from my post above. Taken into consideration that i was referring to tokens, do you agree with my comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP Session ids are random hashes. There is nothing to decrypt at all.

The actual session data is stored on the server side - the session id/token only identifies the session so PHP knows which session data to retrieve.

Comment: i dont necessarily agree that they are random hashes. Session id's could be created for anything (ip, timestamp etc) and can be predictable in many cases

Comment: He's most likely using PHP's builtin sessions though.